# Wrap tags [start] [end] around selected text in textarea with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a textarea where users can input text. With a button, they should be able to wrap a selected text in this textarea with custom tags [start] [end].

```
<button onclick="addTags();">Add Tags to selected Text</button>

<textarea id="user-input" name="user-input" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
```

Example: If the text in the textarea is for example "1 2 3" and user marks "2" and clicks the button the result in the textarea should be "1 [start]2[end] 3".

I am trying no to get a piece of javascript to work, that will do this for me.

I played around with "window.getSelection()". So the question is: What is the right approach for my function?

```
function addTags() {
...
}
```

Comment: You can use multiple inputs in one div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cut the text up: before the selection, the selection, after the selection. Then reassemble with tags.

```js
document.getElementById("add-tag").onclick = () => {
  let txt = document.getElementById("user-input");
  const before = txt.value.substring(0, txt.selectionStart);
  const sel = txt.value.substring(txt.selectionStart, txt.selectionEnd);
  const after = txt.value.substring(txt.selectionEnd);
  txt.value = `${before}[start]${sel}[end]${after}`;
};
```

```html
<button id="add-tag">Add Tags to selected Text</button>

<textarea id="user-input" name="user-input" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
```

TODO: Handle case where nothing is selected.-

Comment: Handle case, simple solution:  `if (txt.selectionStart === txt.selectionEnd) {
    return false;
  }`